# Awk printing lines if column 5 contains a period

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to identify those lines that have a period (.) on it's 5th column, and have as an output their 3rd columns because there i have the tag to identity the lines. I've come up with this :

```
awk '{if ($5 = ".") {print $3}}' file.vcf
```

But my file originally has 42 lines and the result yielded by this has 60, so clearly there's something wrong with my code.

```
wc -l file.vcf
  42
awk '{if ($5 = ".") {print $3}}' file.vcf | wc -l
  60
```

So, desired output: a list with 3rd column content (the name tags of my lines) so as to identify which lines have a period "." on the 5th column.

Any thoughts? Thanks! (i'm on macOSsierra terminal,btw).

Comment: awk if needs double = like `$5=="."`

Comment: `$5=="."` will return true if `$5` contains exactly one period, not a period in the `$5` string

Comment: I'm still wondering how you got 60 lines of output from a 42-line file.

Comment: i had to do a previous step grepping for certain letters, because the file was originally bigger, and i didn't take that into account but then i realized and corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
awk '{if  ( $5 ~ /\./ ) { print $3} }' file.vcf
```

Basically, check to see if the fifth column contains a period (.) ; if yes, print the third column

Comment: And if i wanna "delete that line" instead of printing $3?

Comment: @melunuge92 Replace `~` with `!~`

Comment: The `if` statement here isn't really necessary. `awk '$5 ~ /\./ { print $3 }' file.vcf` accomplishes the same thing.